# Keyboard light hotkey (Fn + F3 and F4) rarely work on an Asus G60J

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, suspend, asus, backlight

Im using Ubuntu 12.04, and my laptop is an Asus G60J.

Specifications:

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Intel i7 720qm

Nvidia gtx 260m

4gb RAM

The laptop always start with the keyboard backlit On. The hotkeys sometimes work, sometimes don't. Generally they always work to turn on the lights, but it is very hard to turn them off. It is really annoying because when the laptop suspend the keyboard remains turned on.

I would like to know what file manage the FN events so I can try to figure it out. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually set the brightness value (between 0 and 3) of the keyboard with the file:

```
/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

The simplest is first to give you the right to modify it:

```
sudo chmod 777 /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

And then change the value, for instance to turn it on:

```
echo 3 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Or turn it off:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

You can set a global shortkey (eg <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd>) for those commands, I'm on KDE then cannot help you for this, just have a look on the settings.

(Note: Maybe the maximum value is not 3 in your case, have a look at `/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/max_brightness`.)

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! max_brightness is 3 but the fn keys still don't work.. But that is not really necessary. Greetings