# Function keys for ASUS n56vm not working

Tags: 12.10, keyboard-layout, asus, function-keys

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 (64bits) (3.5.0-18 kernel) on an ASUS N56VM.
Most <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd> are working except for:

- brightness keys (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>)
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - gamma keys
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - camera
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> - toggle speed

I really like, at least, to have the brightness keys working.

Can you help?
Best Regards

---

```
$ dmesg | grep -i asus 
[    0.000000] DMI: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. N56VM/N56VM, BIOS N56VM.206 04/13/2012
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 00000000cafcc000 00024 (v02 _ASUS_)
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 00000000cafcc078 00074 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 00000000cafdf858 000F4 (v04 _ASUS_ Notebook 01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 00000000cafcc188 136CA (v02 _ASUS_ Notebook 00000013 INTL 20091112)
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 00000000cafdf950 00092 (v03 _ASUS_ Notebook 01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FPDT 00000000cafdf9e8 00044 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: ECDT 00000000cafdfa30 000C1 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 01072009 AMI. 00000005)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 00000000cafdfaf8 0003C (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 01072009 MSFT 00000097)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SLIC 00000000cafdfb38 00176 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 01072009 ASUS 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 00000000cafdfcb0 00038 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 01072009 AMI. 00000005)
[    0.000000] ACPI: BGRT 00000000cafe1090 00038 (v00 _ASUS_ Notebook 01072009 ASUS 00010013)
[    9.670500] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
[    9.671627] asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x1asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 7.9
[    9.671673] asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0x6a0877<6>[    9.672086] input: Asus WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input4
[    9.732438] Registered led device: asus::kbd_backlight
[    9.733242] asus_wmi: Backlight controlled by ACPI video driver
```

Comment: sounds like a driver is missing

Answer (score 3):

This solution for the **FN Keys** worked for me on

## ubuntustudio 12.10 64bit [ASUS N56VM]

(I advice you I'm not an expert)

With a fresh install of ubuntustudio the keyboard backlight and display brightness fn keys [f3, f4, f5, f6] don't work to me, so I did:

#### 1. Download and install: kernel 3.7.0-7 lowlatency

- download these three files: 1) headers_all 2) headers 3)
  image ([here you can find the download links](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lowlatency/3.7.0-7.5))
- from the terminal go in the directory where they have been downloaded
  and then install them with the following commands:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i linux-lowlatency-headers-3.7.0-7_3.7.0-7.5_all.deb
  sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.7.0-7-lowlatency_3.7.0-7.5_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.7.0-7-lowlatency_3.7.0-7.5_amd64.deb
  ```
- restart the system selecting in the grub this new kernel

So now (at least to me) the following fn key works:
**f2** *[wirelss],* **f5** *[brightenss down]*, **f6** *[brightness up]*, **f7** *[turn off screen]*, **f10-f11-f12** *[audio controls]*

#### 2. Write a script to get full permissions on the file we need to control

- run the following commands *[means: go to the folder /init.d -> create a file called asus-kbd_backlight.sh -> open it with gedit]*

  ```
  cd /etc/init.d sudo touch asus-kbd_backlight.sh && gedit asus-kbd_backlight.sh
  ```
- now copy this:

  ```
  /bin/chmod 777 /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
  ```

  and paste it in the file, save and close it
- now go back to the terminal and write the following commands:

  ```
  sudo chmod 744 /etc/init.d/asus-kbd_backlight.sh
  sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/asus-kbd_backlight.sh
  sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/fan-speed-init.sh /etc/rc2.d/S99asus-kbd_backlight.sh
  ```

#### 3. Write two other small shell scripts *[[thanks to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/157986)]*

- open a new file with a texteditor like gedit and write the following:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
  ```
- save it as *i.e.* : asus-keysOff
- open another new file with a texteditor and write the following:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo 3 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
  ```
- save it as *i.e.* : asus-keysOn

#### 4. Assign these scripts to keyboard shortcuts

- go on the Settings Manager -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts
- add a new one, as **Command** choose the file *asus-keysOn* press Ok and in the next dialog box press the keys combination: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
- now to turn off again add a new shortcut, as **Command** choose the file *asus-keysOff* press Ok and in the next dialog box press the keys combination: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

#### 5. Reboot and use the fn keys

It works only on/off with no gradual levels *[it should work with four levels: 0-1-2-3...]* but it works.

hope this could be of help

Answer (score 1):

This is an addendum to the comprehensive answer of kuus, thanks for that.

## A1. Kernel

His solution worked for me on the standard quetzal **kernel (3.5.0)**.

## A2. Write a script to get full permissions on the file we need to control *(can be packed into single command)*

Can be abbreviated into a single (though longish) command, basically added a `chmod 744 asus_kbd_backlight.sh` to be able to echo the text into it.

```
sudo touch /etc/init.d/asus_kbd_backlight.sh && \
sudo chmod 777 /etc/init.d/asus_kbd_backlight.sh && \
sudo echo /bin/chmod 777 "/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness" > /etc/init.d/asus_kbd_backlight.sh && \
sudo chmod 744 /etc/init.d/asus_kbd_backlight.sh && \
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/asus_kbd_backlight.sh && \
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/asus_kbd_backlight.sh /etc/rc2.d/S99asus_kbd_backlight.sh
```

A reboot is necessary to set the permissions. However they can be set manually by simply calling.

```
/bin/chmod 777 "/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness"
```

## A3. Write two other small shell scripts *(can be packed into single command with step-wise brightness control)*

I wrote a somewhat more convenient single script to support stepwise increase/decrease of keyboard backlight brightness.

Usage is:

```
asus_kbd_backlight.sh [-d] (up|down)
```

Script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

kbdSysPath="/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight"
bPot="$kbdSysPath/brightness"
crtB=`cat $bPot`
maxB=`cat "$kbdSysPath/max_brightness"`

if [ $1 = "-d" ]; then
  isDebug=true;
  drctn=$2
else
  drctn=$1
fi

function dbg () { [ $isDebug ] && echo $1; }
function setNewB () {
  dbg "setting new brightness: $newcrtB"
  dbg "$1 > $bPot"
  echo $1 > $bPot
}

dbg "current brightness: $crtB; maximum Brightness: $maxB"

if [ $drctn = "up" ]
then
  if [ $maxB -gt $crtB ]
  then
    newcrtB=$((crtB+1))
    setNewB $newcrtB
  else
    dbg "already at maximum $crtB"
  fi
elif [ $drctn = "down" ]
then
  if [ $crtB -gt 0 ]
  then
    newcrtB=$((crtB-1))
    setNewB $newcrtB
  else
    dbg "already at minimum: $crtB"
  fi
else
  echo "Usage: asus_kbd_backlight [-d] (up|down)
  -d    output debug statements
  up    increase brightness by 1 until maximum value is reached
  down  decrease brightness by 1 until 0 (assumed to be minimum value)"
fi
```

## A4. Assign the script to keyboard shortcuts (KDE-specific)

```
Custom Shortcuts -> Edit -> New -> Global Shorcut -> Command/URL
```

For each shortcut go to the Trigger tab and set <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F4</kbd>

For each shortcut go to the Action tab and specify the command to call, either

```
/path/to/asus_kbd_backlight.sh up
```

or

```
/path/to/asus_kbd_backlight.sh down
```

Answer (score 0):

At least I can give you a solution for the backlight keys. See my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/167418/76387) to a similar question. This one is about Asus n56vz, but the solution may also work for your computer.

Comment: Thank you Jean-Louis but i got the backlight keys working already. You see, Ubuntu 12.10 has brought some improvement.
I need at least to have the brightkeys to work.

Comment: If you follow the link in my answer, you may find a solution for the brightkeys too :-)

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your contributions. But i just found a simplier way.

With user 'root' edit /etc/default/grub by adding 'acpi_osi=' to the following line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
so the line will be:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="

Next run:
 update-grub
and reboot.

You'll have Fn+f5 and Fn+f6 working!!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Install `xbacklight`:

`sudo apt-get install xbacklight`

Then open the dash and type "keyboard" and launch the app, then switch to the "Shortcuts" tab and add two new shortcuts (+ button at the bottom):

1. Called "Backlight +" and running the command `xbacklight -inc 10`
2. Called "Backlight -" and running the command `xbacklight -dec 10`

Then map these commands to whatever key combo you want (I use Alt+F5 and Alt+F6).  It's not a perfect solution, but it is a workaround, and a lot easier than using the "Brightness and Lock" GUI.

Hope this was helpful to someone!