# Brightness keyboard buttons do not work on Asus 1225c

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness, asus

I have problem with my new *netbook*. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I can't use my brightness key's (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd>). When i use them OSD appears and indicates the increase or decrease of brightness but nothing really happens to screen. I used this command from terminal(and it worked):

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=xx
```

But I want use my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221826/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copy-Paste from here the commands below (to your terminal) , with order and one at time

**First**

```
sudo sed 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="/' -i /etc/default/grub
```

**Second**

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system and see if Fn (for brightness) works.

Comment: Also fixed my problem for ASUS S551LB.

Comment: Fixes the brightness buttons for ASUS G56jr too! Thank you!

Comment: if this doesn't work for Asus g56jr, check this: http://askubuntu.com/a/505790/265366