# My brightness control buttons are not working on my Packard Bell netbook

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, brightness, function-keys

I have a Packard Bell DOT S netbook. First I installed Ubuntu on it. I noticed that I couldn't use my brightness control buttons (F11 F12). I saw the little bar like it is changing its brightness, but actually it did nothing. Then I found a command line:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And there I edited this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

After it just worked perfectly, but sadly my wifi went wonky and I couldn't use it actually on Ubuntu so I decided to get Lubuntu. Everything was fine with it, but still I cannot use the brightness buttons. I tried the previous method, but it just says: `sudo: gedit: command not found`

I looked for another solution, and I found this line:

```
sudo sed 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="/' -i /etc/default/grub
```

Before that, I saw the same thing as in Ubuntu: saw the bar is changing, but actually no change in the brightness. So I tried this method, rebooted, and now even that bar has disappeared.

At least help me to get back to the point I started. But ultimately I'd like to use my brightness control buttons!

Comment: After the second command (sudo sed 's....) did you update the grub ? `sudo update-grub`  You can also try 2 more parameters `apci_osi=Linux` and `acpi_backlight=vendor` Do not forget to update grub and and reboot for changes to take effect. Also acpi-support package is not installed in Lubuntu I think. Try `sudo apt-get install acpi-support`

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this, but I'm quite the rookie in linux. So can you write down what exactly i should type in the terminal? It would be a huuuuuuge help. Thanks in advance:) (Also, I installed acpi-support as you suggested)

Comment: See Bruno's answer. I think now it's clear (for a rookie too).

Comment: If it doesnt work to you, try this another solution:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/230609/brightness-keyboard-buttons-do-not-work-on-asus-1225c/230623#230623

Answer (score 2):

Like already mentioned, try adding to that `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line `acpi_osi=Linux` or `acpi_backlight=vendor` or both (one of them should work).
To edit the file you can use `nano`. It works in the terminal and should already be installed by default, and is easy to use:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

In nano editor you can save the file with a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Y(es)</kbd>

Alternatively you can use gedit editor. Gedit is the default (pre-installed) editor in Ubuntu (vanilla).

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

After editing the file (proofread twice !) run this command to update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot the computer and test if it worked.

Comment: Done it i suppose. Here's my edited line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux" Still no change. Nothing seems to happen

Comment: If it doesn't work, then I don't know. I had the same problem with another laptop (an Acer) and adding `acpi_osi=Linux` works in my case. Have you tried with just `acpi_osi=Linux`?

Comment: Yeah I did as you said. And I copied the actual line in my comment. So yes, I wrote the Linux one in it too... :/

Comment: Try `acpi_osi=` , remove the other two entries. (do not forget to update-grub after editing). Reboot for changes to take effect. The line should read **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="**

Comment: No change, nothing happens, the brightness bar still refuse to appear and no change in the brightness itself...

Comment: Then no parameters will work for you. Additional you can upgrade to a newer kernel (or version of Ubuntu), that maybe ACPI supported better there. Also read this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2156192), it might helps you to resolve the problem. The important thing there is to have a result in `acpi_listen` command.