# Fn keys for brightness not working on Asus X551MAV­-SX366GB

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, asus, function-keys

Brightness should be controlled by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>.
Nothing happens when I press these keys.
My computer is a Asus X551MAV­-SX366GB and I'm using Lubuntu 14.04

Comment: This is a known issue with Asus laptops. This post helped me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/489247/14-04-asus-g56jr-fn-brightness-control (I assigned another keyboard shortcut for `xbacklight`).

Comment: Not working for me :-(

Comment: Well, I can now adjust brightness in the system settings, but not through fn keys.

Comment: After changing this in my /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=" I now kan use the Fn keys :-) It still starts out with full brightness. Are there any way to make the computer start up on a lower brightness level? E.g. like the one I left it with?

Comment: xbacklight was not installed, so I had to install it first. It seems to word fine :-)

Comment: Here is the summary of what I did: I created the file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf as described here [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/363087/13-10-cant-adjust-dell-laptop-backlight/401311#401311). Then I changed /etc/default/grub as described above and ran "update-grub" from the command line. And at last I did the xbacklight thing.

Comment: Have done that now, if that was what you meant...

Comment: Yeah exactly :) Great job -  I prettified it a bit so that people who come here can get it all at a glance (if you did something else, please edit/add it there!). Oh and I deleted all coments here for cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the summary of what I did:

1. I created the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` as described here [13.10 Can't Adjust Dell Laptop Backlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363087/13-10-cant-adjust-dell-laptop-backlight/401311#401311):

   ```
   Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection
   ```
2. Then I changed one line in`/etc/default/grub so it looked like this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=" and ran`sudo update-grub` from the command line.
3. Install [xbacklight](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xbacklight) [image: Install xbacklight] if not already installed `sudo apt-get install xbacklight`. Then I put `xbacklight -set 50` to autostart applications.
4. Reboot

This worked for me.

Comment: Hmmmm. Not working with Xubuntu on the same machine :-( I see the indicator, when I press function keys, but nothing happens.