# Assigning a default Keyboard backlight

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I have installed UBUNTU 14.04 on an Asus G56JK laptop with keyboard backlight.
The keyboard backlight control function keys are working properly, allowing four levels of brightness from 0 (no light) to 3 (the brightest).
When I start the computer, the default level is 0.

Is it possible to set the default setting of brightness to a certain level?

Comment: Check this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/489247/14-04-asus-g56jr-fn-brightness-control

Comment: Thanks - This post refers to display backlight not keyboard backlight. For display backlight, I have the solution and posted an answer if people are still questionning about it.

Answer (score 1):

Progressing - Partial answer

Create  the file `asus-nb-wmi.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d/`:

```
sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/asus-nb-wmi.conf
```

Edit the file :

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/asus-nb-wmi.conf
```

Enter : `asus-nb-wmi`

Save

Reboot

On reboot, the backlight level is kept at the same level as before rebooting.

Unfortunately, it does not work for a cold boot.

Comment: Are you still having the device? If yes, had you ever found the complete solution? If yes, then please update the answer. If no, then I have a suggestion. I think you should have included the module that is supposed to be loaded during boot time in `/etc/modules` file, not files in `/etc/modprobe.d` directory. Can you check and verify?

Comment: Could you please update your answer with the information requested in above comment? ^

Comment: Hello - Sorry I do not own this machine any longer. However, and so far I can recall, the installation of UBUNTU 16.04 solved the problem for me, giving an appropriate keyboard backlight straight from a cold boot.