# Backlight change with FN keys do not work on Asus

Tags: kde, brightness, asus, backlight

Asus g53 laptop, Ubuntu 14.04, KDE 4.13.3

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+{<kbd>f5</kbd><kbd>f6</kbd>} should change the screen brightness but only the animation appears with the panel (I can increase the values but the brightness does no change)

1. I have already tried to add this to grub

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```

   Does not work.
2. I tried this one too, I do not know what should happen after the first command but I just got back the console without anything seeming to happen:

   [Brightness keyboard buttons do not work on Asus 1225c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230609/brightness-keyboard-buttons-do-not-work-on-asus-1225c)
3. I have also installed this [dkms package found on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2005756&page=5&p=12057336#post12057336)

On GNOME and Unity this function works like a charm. Why not on KDE?
Keyboard backlight is working on KDE.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Save, then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart computer.

The function keys <kbd>Fn</kbd>+{<kbd>f5</kbd><kbd>f6</kbd>} should now be active.

This may need to be done again after upgrading the system, as the grub file may be modified during the upgrade procedure.

Comment: what device did you test this on? Doesn't work on my Asus. And it's a big hammer that might break other functions