# Permanent permission change to sys file

Tags: permissions

I'd like to always give my user the permission to write on a specific file located in the /sys folder.
This because in the [solution I posted here](https://askubuntu.com/a/234473/117677) I have the problem that every time I reboot I have to reset the permission on the file with chmod.

I tried to follow [this guide](http://recom.se/2010/06/maintain-file-permissions-after-reboot-linux/) but it didn't work. According to this I have to create a sh script, mine consiste in just this line:

```
/bin/chmod 644 /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer here to be the best answer
https://superuser.com/questions/484678/cant-write-to-file-sys-class-backlight-acpi-video0-brightness-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the script to /etc/init.d? You have to symlink the script you wrote to /etc/init.d so that it runs at startup.

```
sudo chmod 744 /etc/init.d/fan-speed-init.sh
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/fan-speed-init.sh
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/fan-speed-init.sh /etc/rc2.d/S99fan-speed-init.sh
```

Comment: yes you're right I skipped that step because in that guide i've read "This multiple linking could be done smarter by issuing the update-rc.d -f fan-speed-init.sh start 99 2 3 4 5 .". Thanks for your help