# Run sudo script at startup under 15.04 using 'systemd'

Tags: asus, systemd

I would like to run a script to turn the keyboard backlight off on my Asus at login ([this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366578/start-asus-laptop-ux32vd-with-keyboard-backlight-off) did not work).  Before the introduction of `systemd` in Ubuntu 15.04, I did this through  `/etc/rc.local` using the command `(sleep 10 && echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness)`.  However, under `systemd`, this no longer works.

I tried to follow [the instructions here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202698/) to create a `systemd service`.  But that didn't work.  This is the text I used:

> [Unit]
>      Description=MBWD Keyboard Backlight OFF script
>
> [Service]
>      Type=oneshot
>      ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/keyboard_backlight.sh
>      #RemainAfterExit=yes
>   [Install]
>      WantedBy=multi-user.target

To call this script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

I then enabled the service, started the service, and used the `systemctl preset` command to enable the service at startup (I think that's what it does).

After all this, the `systemctl status` command indicates that the service is enabled, and when I `systemctl start` the service it does dim the keyboard.  And, on reboot, that is at startup, it may work, because the keyboard does turn off when Ubuntu starts up.

HOWEVER, once I get to my login screen and login, the keyboard light comes back on.  I've tried to finesse this issue by using both `sleep 20` in the script and by [creating](http://jason.the-graham.com/2013/03/06/how-to-use-systemd-timers/) a `systemd.timer` unit. Neither worked.

Can anyone help???

Comment: Have you tried using the After directive of systemd to make it run after the window manager has started ? something like  After=lightdm.service

Comment: Thanks aklmie, that did not work though.  I put `After=lightdm.service` in the `[Unit]` section, and no go.  I appreciate the help -- any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by using an `rc-local.service` and `/etc/rc.local` instead of creating a separate systemd service. Here is what I did:

1. In terminal: `systemctl enable rc-local.service`
2. In `/etc/rc.local` I put the following:

**#!/bin/sh -e
(sleep 20 && echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness)
exit 0**

3. Make `/etc/rc.local` executable:

**sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc.local**

4. To confirm, check the status of `rc-local.service`

**systemctl status rc-local.service**

It should show green and say active. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

Surely not the best answer but you can switch from systemd to upstart by installing the package upstart-sysv.

```
sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm hoping to stay in systemd given that Canonical switched to it as the default.