# fn keys to change keyboard blacklights not working

Tags: 12.04, grub2, keyboard, shortcut-keys

The fn + f3 and fn + f4 are not working, the others seem to be working fine. 
This is what I tried to do to fix it: 
I opened the grub file using gedit, changed the permission. 
changed:
RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash “
into: 
RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor“

But I can't save the file, because it couldn't store a copy. 
Any advice?

edit: sometimes they seem to work, sometimes notting happens. I can turn on the lights using fn + f4 and by repeadetly clicking fn + f3 and f4, they will eventually turn off. WTF

Comment: What hardware are you running on?

Comment: I have an Asus G60JX. intel core i7, nvidia geforce GTS 360M

Comment: Try an external USB keyboard to see if the problem is specific to the keyboard or runs deeper.

Comment: The keys work fine on windows 7, I don't have an external keyboard with fn keys

Answer (score 0):

Google gave with the following [bug repport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/533690). Apparently there is a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~flozz/+archive/flozz) which [fixes](https://launchpad.net/asus-keyboard-backlight) it.

Please open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Copy & Paste the following lines:

- On a 64-bit Ubuntu

> wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/flozz/flozz/ubuntu/pool/main/a/asus-kbd-backlight/asus-kbd-backlight_0.1~ppa5_amd64.deb
>   sudo dpkg -i asus-kbd-backlight_0.1~ppa5_amd64.deb

- On a 32-bit Ubuntu

> wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/flozz/flozz/ubuntu/pool/main/a/asus-kbd-backlight/asus-kbd-backlight_0.1~ppa5_i386.deb
>   sudo dpkg -i asus-kbd-backlight_0.1~ppa5_i386.deb

Reboot your system.

Comment: hey ty for your response, but I get this error when trying to update :W: GPG-fout: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: De volgende ondertekeningen konden niet geverifieerd worden omdat de publieke sleutel niet beschikbaar is: NO_PUBKEY 3C9A6980F827E01E 
ok basicly it says: public key not availeble so it can't verify the signatures

Comment: I've changed my answer. Please the new one.

Comment: When I turn my keyboard blacklights off, they turn inmediatly back on. So I'm able to turn them off.

Comment: Do those commands do anything for you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/134021/keyboard-light-hotkey-fn-f3-and-f4-rarely-work-on-an-asus-g60j/157986#157986

Comment: yes I'm able to turn them off correctly with echo 0 > /sys/class/.. 
when I try to turn them off with fn + f3, they turn on again. Basicly a flickering keyboard :p